# ¿Cómo traducir "How the hell" (y otras frases similares) al castellano?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

Juraría que en películas y demás lo traducen por **¿Cómo demonios?** o **¿Cómo diablos?** pero no estoy seguro, ¿existe algún tipo de documentación al respecto de este tipo de frases que, traducidas literalmente, no suenan bien?

Comment: La pregunta suena interesante pero no estoy seguro de entenderla. No sé si buscas alternativas más naturales para "how the hell" o si buscas algún compendio más extenso de frases típicas que no se pueden traducir literalmente.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo: yo entiendo que lo segundo: un compendio de frases ...

Comment: Sí, el título de la pregunta parece indicar lo primero, pero el cuerpo de la misma lo segundo. Yo he supuesto que es lo segundo.

Comment: @Lola claro, yo también, pero el título de la pregunta dice que es lo primero...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, & Nox: eso puede pasar al poner primero el titulo de la pregunta, luego te pones a redactar y el cuerpo de la pregunta "sale" diferente de la inicialmente planeado...

Comment: Pues sí, en un principio iba a preguntar solo por esa frase pero al final.. pues.

Comment: También hay que tener en cuenta si es para texto escritos o para doblaje (como hablas de películas...) ya que para doblaje tiene que encajar más o menos con el movimiento de la boca del personaje y a veces eso hace que se traduzcan algunas expresiones de una forma un tanto extraña

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si buscas "traducción expresiones inglesas" en Google te salen artículos muy interesantes, como [este](http://www.fromspaintouk.com/2012/08/02/expresiones-inglesas-que-debes-conocer/) con más de 300 expresiones (aunque curiosamente no viene ninguna del tipo *how/what the hell*). Lo que ya no sé es si habrá algún texto oficial de alguna escuela de traducción e interpretación que aborde el tema.

Si nos centramos en *how the hell*, en el CORDE aparecen registros de "cómo demonios" desde el siglo XIX:

> *¿Cómo demonios lo he de saber?*
>
> Emilia Pardo Bazán, "Los pazos de Ulloa", España (1886)
>
> ---
>
> *Gracias, amigo mío; pero ¿cómo demonios permites que te llamen Palique, teniendo tan bonito nombre?*
>
> Wenceslao Ayguals de Izco, "La Bruja de Madrid", España (1850)

Si ampliamos el rango a las expresiones con "qué demonios" se pueden encontrar desde principios de dicho siglo. Y lo curioso es que he encontrado un texto que podría explicar por qué nosotros decimos "demonios" en vez de "infiernos" (como he visto traducido en algunos cómics):

> *—¿Adónde va, señor don Quijote? ¿Qué demonios lleva en el pecho que le incitan a ir contra nuestra fe católica?*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha", España (1605)

Cierto es que aquí el término "demonios" suena algo más literal que el figurado actual, pero como ves, la expresión se usa desde hace al menos medio milenio.

Comment: Por lo tanto, este tipo de traducciones no literales se dan porque, muy posiblemente, en el pasado algún autor relevante castellano así lo "*ha decidido*"

Comment: @Alex se dan porque el castellano tiene sus propias expresiones con sus propios orígenes. Una cosa que te enseñan en las escuelas de traducción es que nunca se deben traducir los textos de forma literal, sino de forma que los hablantes de ambos idiomas lean cada uno sus textos y se formen en sus cabezas la misma idea. Si un inglés se forma la misma idea con "how the hell" que un español con "cómo demonios", la traducción es correcta.

Comment: @Alex por supuesto, en muchas ocasiones no será posible encontrar una expresión que haga que ambos se formen la misma idea, por lo que el objetivo será encontrar aquella que haga que se forme una idea lo más cercana posible a la original. Pero insisto en el concepto de traducir las ideas subyacentes al texto más que el texto en sí, usando siempre palabras y expresiones que ya existan en nuestro habla corriente, sin necesidad de forzar expresiones o inventarse nuevas.

Comment: Entiendo. Muy interesante el mundo de la traducción, gracias por la info!

Comment: @Alex un placer. Nótese que yo soy informático de profesión, aunque el mundo de la traducción me apasiona. Conozco a varios traductores que son los que me han contado este tipo de cosas, que debo decir que me han ayudado mucho.

Comment: Con permiso de Carlos, a mí este tipo de traducciones, aún siendo correctas y teniendo un origen añejo como ya demuestra él mismo, siempre me parecieron un intento de superar algún tipo de censura(incluso una censura propia del traductores/productores/etc. a sí mismos, que no es cuestión de ponerse anti-sistema, aunque bien podría) por parte del traductor por ser palabras "malsonantes", no usando las expresiones que realmente se oyen en la calle todos los días y... (perdón, no me cabe en un comentario)

Comment: ... que corresponden al significado original perfectamente, como por ejemplo, en este caso: _¡¿Qué cojones!?_, _¡¿Qué coño?!_; y peores lindezas que decimos todos, incluidos los que tenemos otros recursos. Por que, lo que está claro, es que este tipo de expresiones del tipo _¡Cómo demonios!_, yo no las he oído en mi vida fuera de películas y demás, donde, sinceramente, en vez de sonarme correctas aún siéndolo, siempre me sonaron a sacadas de algún comic del Capitán Trueno de hace cincuenta años.

Comment: Perdón de nuevo :P , solo quería que constara que el comentario anterior iba con ánimo de complementar o añadir, no de corregir.

Comment: @Nox y no te quito razón. Ciertamente, el uso de "demonios" es anecdótico en el habla corriente. Suena novelero o peliculero hoy día, pero no raro. Si se intenta reflejar el habla cotidiana habría que usar otras expresiones. Puede ser un tema de debate bastante interesante.

Comment: @Nox En todo caso, "demonio" podía ser una palabra fuerte en el uso de según qué época, de ahí surgió su eufemismo "diantre", que también se usa (_¿qué diantres...?_) incluso desde antes (siglo XVIII).

Comment: @Carlos Alejo Correcto. Solo tenía que decirlo, es algo que siempre me ha fastidiado mucho, que suelten esas expresiones como si fueran de uso cotidiano, y para más inri, casi siempre en situaciones extremas, como para pararte a buscar un eufemismo. En fin.